# Binary Search for searching String Array in Java

Tags: java

```java
public static int binarySearch(String employee[], String searchElement){

    int startingIndex = 0;
    int lastIndex = employee.length-1;

    while(startingIndex <= lastIndex){

        int midIndex= startingIndex + (lastIndex) / 2;
        int result = searchElement.compareTo(employee[midIndex]);

        if(result == 0)
            return midIndex;
        else if(result>0)
            startingIndex = midIndex + 1;
        else
            lastIndex = midIndex - 1;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

I made this method in my class but it is always returning 1 index smaller than the original value, For instance, the element I'm searching is at 4th index, it is returning it as 3rd index. The full code is at https://pastebin.com/KAh7KgZ3

I was expecting the method to return the original value.

Comment: Maybe try `(startingIndex + lastIndex)/2?` instead of only dividing `lastIndex`?

Comment: Tried that already with different variations but the error remains same

Comment: How can you do a binary search if your data is not pre-sorted? The data file you provided is not in any kind of order.

Comment: What sort of order should the file follow?